# Google Chrome opened in incognito mode by an application

Tags: google-chrome

I set up my Chrome to use incongnito mode by default by modifying the Desktop icon properties. It is working fine. But, Chrome is set up as default browser my in Windows 7 and whenever an application (Outlook, yammer client, Skype, etc.) opens a link it is opened in Chrome which not using incognito mode. How is possible to set up the whole environment in that way it always opens urls in Google Chrome which uses incognito mode.

I have searched for this question but 99 per cent of the answers is about the icon property modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this option was removed from chrome since Chrome 9, by request of a user. It's possible to fix this, but from Windows 7 and on it requires third party programs to edit the arguments for Chrome to start up in Incognito mode. You're supposed to add `"-incognito"` to the startup arguments for HTTP links.

[See the following link.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3By29eRzWZo)